# Using Javascript can you get the value from a session attribute set by servlet in the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have a servlet that forwards to a HTML page, using redirect. Because I am using ajax and php on the html page to do other functions. Can turn into a jsp. Is there a way I can get the name -"poNumber" I get in servlet in the session attributes. I was to get it and display it's value.

I am new to programming.

Can get this working in jsp.

However need to get this working in a html page. Can I do it with javascript?

I have tried:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var purchaseOrderNo = session.getAttribrute("pONumb");
      document.write("pONumb");
      </script> [
```

This does not output any values on the HTML page.

Tried:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var purchaseOrderNo = (String) session.getAttribrute("pONumb");
           document.write("pONumb");
           </script>
```

Again get no output on page.

Tried:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            String purchaseOrderNo = (String) session.getAttribrute("pONumb");
            document.write("pONumb");
            </script>
```

Again get no output on page?

Can not think of any thing else to try. The servlet that redirects to this HTML page creates and set session attribute pONumb.

Comment: Can you add the complete JSP to the question? What is the HTML output you _are_ seeing? If the JSP is outputting the `<script>` block you might want to try `var purchaseOrderNo = <%= session.getAttribrute("pONumb"); %>`

Comment: What is `(String) session.getAttribrute("pONumb");`? It is not even a correct JavaScript syntax... And JAVA is not the same as JavaScript. Read more about JSP here: [Wikipedia - JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP)

Answer (score 43):

No, you can't. JavaScript is executed on the client side (browser), while the session data is stored on the server.

However, you can expose session variables for JavaScript in several ways:

- a hidden input field storing the variable as its value and reading it through the DOM API
- an HTML5 data attribute which you can read through the DOM
- storing it as a cookie and accessing it through JavaScript
- injecting it directly in the JS code, if you have it inline

In JSP you'd have something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pONumb" value="${sessionScope.pONumb} />
```

or:

```
<div id="product" data-prodnumber="${sessionScope.pONumb}" />
```

Then in JS:

```
// you can find a more efficient way to select the input you want
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), len = inputs.length, i, pONumb;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name == "pONumb") {
        pONumb = inputs[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

or:

```
var product = document.getElementById("product"), pONumb;
pONumb = product.getAttribute("data-prodnumber");
```

The inline example is the most straightforward, but if you then want to store your JavaScript code as an external resource ([the recommended way](http://books.google.com/books/about/High_performance_web_sites.html?id=jRVlgNDOr60C)) it won't be feasible.

```
<script>
    var pONumb = ${sessionScope.pONumb};
    [...]
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I still would like to ask why the inline example (the last one) does not work if the JS code is in an external file. Thanks!

Comment: You could have it in an external file, but the file would need to be pre-processed, you can no-longer serve it as a static file. You lose a bunch of advantages that way - caching, CDNs etc.

Comment: Using a `meta` tag (versus a hidden input) is also an option

Answer (score 5):

```
<%
String session_val = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionval"); 
System.out.println("session_val"+session_val);
%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var session_obj= '<%=session_val%>';
alert("session_obj"+session_obj);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code may help you to achieve session attribution inside java script:

```
var name = '<%= session.getAttribute("username") %>';
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Comment: this indeed helped me - could you tell me, why to use the <% %> tags inside the <script></script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $sessionDetails = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');

    if (!empty($sessionDetails)) {


        $loginFlag = 1;
        # code...
    }else{
        $loginFlag =  0;
    }


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var sessionValue = '<?php echo $loginFlag; ?>';
    if (sessionValue = 0) {

        //model show
    }
</script>
```