# onClick to another JSP doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, session

I been having problems on my onclick function to another JSP.
I wanted to check whether if the session attribute is the same as **John** or **Mark** from my **display.jsp**, then it will display on **new.jsp** with that name.
I have a **login.jsp** and successfully works on **display.jsp** where it able to display name out by using session in ValidationServlet.
After implementing the code in **display.jsp**, I keep getting requested resource () is not available.
Stuck there for 3 days already and kinda lost now.
Hope you guys could help me out with it, thanks in advance.

**This is my display.jsp code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display</h1>
        Welcome <b><%=session.getAttribute("name")%></b>,
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="loan" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" value="New" onClick="new()"/>
                    </form>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                        function new(){          
                            if (session.getAttribute("name") === "John") {
                                session.setAttribute("name", "John");
                                document.new.action="new.jsp";
                            }
                            if (session.getAttribute("name") === "Mark") {
                                session.setAttribute("name", "Mark");
                                document.new.action="new.jsp";
                            } else {
                                session.setAttribute("name", null);
                                document.new.action="new.jsp";
                            }
                            new.submit();
                        }
                    </SCRIPT>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my new.jsp code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New</h1>
        Hello <b><%=session.getAttribute("name")%></b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost 100% sure that you have a problem with mapping... You'll need to pass through a Servlet to get the session variables.

Comment: Post your full stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the info, shinjw. It works now xD

Answer (score 2):

You will get the session variable like beelow:

```
var firstName='<%= session.getAttribute("name")%>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access session variable from java script, since it executes on client side, what is the output for this piece of code `session.getAttribute("name")` , Are you getting expected value?

Alternatively you can fallow this link [Access session variables in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918314/using-javascript-can-you-get-the-value-from-a-session-attribute-set-by-servlet-i)