# How to make HTTP JavaScript request in login session

Tags: javascript, json, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I realized that SharePoint exposes a REST GET API. While I am logged into SharePoint, I am able to invoke the API using my browser URL bar without explicitly writing credentials into the GET request. However, I would like to be able to make a request based on that same session in a JavaScript HTTP request (without filling in credentials). Is that possible? If so, how does one do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Session variables and set them in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-to-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript)

Comment: It depends on what variable I need to obtain. From what I can see it should either be a Bearer token or basic auth (username+password). I will have to look into that before I can answer you

Comment: No, it does not answer my question. The answer does not tell me how to obtain the parameters I need. Or do you know the names of them, @ControlAltDel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918314/using-javascript-can-you-get-the-value-from-a-session-attribute-set-by-servlet-i/6918356

Comment: From what I can see: No, it does not answer my question. It does _not_ tell me 1) what parameters to obtain, 2) whether they can be obtained, 3) how to make the request